# I have problem in making Jarvis, opening YouTube

Tags: python

Here is my code -

```
elif 'open YouTube' in query:
    webbrowser.open('youtube.com')
```

This code does not open YouTube, please check for any problem

Comment: You need to share some more code about the problem and some debug logs that points to the problem.

Comment: This is the only code in which I am having problem. Other things are woking fine

Answer (score 1):

if you just type youtube.com it will not work but if you replace if with https://www.youtube.com/  it will work just run the code below

```
elif 'open YouTube' in query:
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/')
```

Comment: It really worked!! It seemed like this code will work for Mac and it really did. Thank you!! It was really helpful!